# Trying to get property of non-object Notice in custom avatar function for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

The following custom avatar functions works fine, but I get the following notice

> "Trying to get property of non-object in..."

The notice says the problem is on the last part of the function I pasted here - I marked it in the code (look for `<-- Notice mentions this line`)

Any idea how to fix this? I am stuck...

```
function test_get_avatar($avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt) {
if (!is_numeric($id_or_email)) {
    if (is_string($id_or_email)) {
        $user = get_user_by('email', $id_or_email);
        $id_or_email = $user->ID;
    } else if (is_object($id_or_email)) {
        if (!empty($id_or_email->ID)) {
            $id_or_email = $id_or_email->ID;
        }

        if (!empty( $id_or_email->comment_author_email)) {
            $user = get_user_by('email', $id_or_email->comment_author_email);
            $id_or_email = $user->ID; <-- Notice mentions this line
        }
    }
}

$avatar_id = get_user_meta($id_or_email, 'nicobartes_user_avatar', true);
...
```

Comment: `$user` is not an object.... so by definition (in PHP) it can not contain an attribute referenced as `ID`. Where is `$user` set?

Comment: @martin - everthing is possible but im not able to solve my problem with your url to the Reference page... I already searched similar questions and found nothing so far. So i need help. Would be awesome if someone helps me out. best

Comment: Are you seriously telling me you [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26572398/3536236) and you still don't know how to solve your issue?

Comment: Now i did :) thx

Comment: Sorry, I should have linked that answer directly in the first instance, rather than just the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because [get_user_by()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) can fail and return false.  At that point you won't have a wp user object.  A test around this code would be:

```
if ($user = get_user_by('email', $id_or_email->comment_author_email)) {
    $id_or_email = $user->ID; 
} else {
    //Whatever you want to do when this lookup fails
    $id_or_email = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
$user = get_user_by('email', $id_or_email->comment_author_email);
```

You should check the value of `$user` before attempting to get the id on the next line. According to the [Wordpress docs](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/), it could potentially be false if no user is found.